# Towers Of Hanoi Java

Tags: java, towers-of-hanoi

This is a homework that I was working on. I have created 2 classes to play Towers of Hanoi. The first one is the basically a runner to run the actual game class.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class TowersRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TowersOfHanoi towers = new TowersOfHanoi();
        towers.TowersOfHanoi()
    }
}

public class TowersOfHanoi {
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        System.out.println("Please enter the starting " + "number of discs to move:");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num_of_discs = scanner.nextInt();

        solve(num_of_discs, 'A', 'B', 'C');
    }

    public static void solve(int first_disc, char aTower, char bTower, char cTower) {
        if (first_disc == 1) {
            System.out.println("Disk 1 on tower " + aTower + " moving to tower " + cTower);
        } else {
            solve(first_disc - 1, aTower, cTower, bTower);
            System.out.println("Disk " + first_disc + " on tower " + aTower + " moving to tower " + cTower);
            solve(first_disc - 1, bTower, aTower, cTower);
        }
    }
}
```

What I need help with is to make the `TowersOfHanoi` class to run from my `TowersRunner` class.   I also need to implement a counter display how many times it took for the game to run until the game is finished in my `TowersOfHanoi` class. Basically I need line that is `System.out.println("It took" + counter + "turns to finish.");`

I don't know how to implement the counter correctly. Also, can't make the runner class to run the `TowersOfHanoi`. The `TowersOfHanoi` class runs fine by itself but the requirment for the homework is we need at least 2 classes min.

Help would be much appreciated!!! Please I am a novice in Java and programming in general please don't go too advanced on me. :D

Comment: This site pretty much works on specific questions. It isn't really a good forum to teach you how to do a particular concept. You might want to narrow this down to a question or two instead of just a general "Please help me" request.

Comment: Yes, I have noticed that but did you read my question above? I thought I was clear enough on my question. Thanks

Comment: I don't even see a question in that. I searched the post for a ? mark but didn't find a single one.  Can you point me to it?

Comment: Ok, sorry I was not clear enough. How do I impelment a counter into the TowersOfHanoi class to count how many turns it took to finish the game?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the main-Function in the TowersOfHanoi class.
Instead, replace your TowersRunner main(String args[]) method with

```
public static void main(String[] args) {    
    System.out.println("Please enter the starting " + "number of discs to move:");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int num_of_discs = scanner.nextInt();
    TowersOfHanoi.solve(num_of_discs, 'A', 'B', 'C');
}
```

Comment: That is awesome! Thanks for the help. How do I thank you on this site?

Comment: You vote up the answer and click the check mark below. It will become green and my answer would then be marked as the accepted one :)

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass the counter in the function and have it be incremented. For example:

```
public static void solve(int first_disc, char aTower, char bTower, char cTower, int counter) {
    System.out.println("Currently on turn #" + counter);

    if (first_disc == 1) {
        System.out.println("Disk 1 on tower " + aTower + " moving to tower " + cTower);
    } else {
        solve(first_disc - 1, aTower, cTower, bTower, counter + 1);
        System.out.println("Disk " + first_disc + " on tower " + aTower + " moving to tower " + cTower);
        solve(first_disc - 1, bTower, aTower, cTower, counter + 1);
    }
}
```

In the first call of `solve`, you would pass in 1. As you can see, each time `solve` is called recursively, the counter is incremented.

I'll leave you to adapt this to return the final value of counter :) If you just need the final value, you don't need to add a parameter at all. Just make the function return `int` instead of `void` then try and figure out how you would make it return the value you want.